# Connect to external SQLite Database

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlite

I have a website, which is powered by an **SQLite** database (essentially a `db` file). Sometimes it is required to look at my database from other machines (within the same local network). For that purpose I currently use [sqlite-web](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlite-web) which provides a mini SQL web viewer into my `db` file.

Since **sqlite-web**'s functionality is quite limited, I am wondering whether there are ways to let other machines connect to my local `db` file via normal desktop applications (such as DataGrip). Similar to how one can connect to postgres via `jdbc:postgresql://host:port`. Or is this not possible with SQLite?

Edit: I would like to limit the access (e.g. via username + password or a generic PIN), as I don't want everyone in the network to be able to connect to my db.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sqlite-database)?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Yeah, but this only works with files (hence they write "specify a file path to the database file"). As Kevin suggests, if I share the file via a network path, this could work. I guess, I was wondering whether there are ways, which doesn't rely on file paths (and instead "publish" the `db` via a host+port, maybe SSH).

Comment: Well, not that I know about. It _is_ a file, right?

Comment: What I meant is, instead of exposing the file directly, wouldn't it be nice to host the database as a server, and let clients connect to it properly.

Comment: Fair enough, but why not use a database server proper? [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) says "A good rule of thumb is to avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed directly (without an intervening application server) and simultaneously from many computers over a network."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the drive and then use the file path of the mapping.

Or use remote desktop to access directly
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c

Comment: How would I limit access though? I don't want everyone in the network to be able to connect to my db.

Comment: You could password protect so that only you can map the drive in the first place. Using Samba on linux. It can be done on windows too but I dont know the exact process.

Comment: Another option is to use ssh or remote desktop to the machine with the database.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any details on what I would need to setup SSH?

Comment: What are the operating systems being used?

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: And the machine the db is on is windows 10?